# Xaml Grid element to PDF

Tags: wpf, pdf

I need to create a pdf file from wpf C# application. I need to apply style to the pdf exactly the same as XAML. I can't just copy the xaml page since the data can be different when the pdf is being created. I'll have to do the data processing when the user clicks export button. The pdf will have text, images and background images. I was thinking to have an html file for designing the pdf and then pass the data. But I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestion or sample example would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes by exporting to XPS then convrting to PDF, by using a converter like: [NiXPS](http://nixps.blogspot.hu/2008/04/convert-xps-to-pdf.html).

Here is an example for this:

```
    private void SaveVisuals(XpsDocumentWriter xpsdw, List<Visual> vc)
{
    // Setup for writing multiple visuals
    VisualsToXpsDocument vToXpsD = (VisualsToXpsDocument)xpsdw.CreateVisualsCollator();

    // Iterate through all visuals in the collection 
    foreach (Visual v in vc)
    {
        vToXpsD.Write(v);   //Write each visual to single page
    }

    // End writing multiple visuals
    vToXpsD.EndBatchWrite();
}
```

More on this: [On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.visualstoxpsdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Another way could be to render your document into an image first, then you can easily put your image to a PDF file (of course this has some disadvantages, but this is a quick way to go).

For converting HTML to PDF you could be using [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) for example, but there are many different tools out there.

Here you can find a .NET implementation: [Pdf API and HTML to PDF Converter for .NET](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx)

If you want to render your Visuals to image, any WPF Visual object can be rendered into a bitmap using [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx).

Example from MSDN:

```
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        drawingContext.DrawText(text, new Point(2, 2));
        drawingContext.Close();

        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(180, 180, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
        myImage.Source = bmp;
```

You can render any visual this way. You don't have to display it, but you can. 
If you want to keep up the responsiveness of the UI you should do this export operation in a seperate thread, not the event processing thread.

Comment: Any sample application for second suggestion as well,i.e., converting to image and then rendering?

Comment: So while the image is being rendered, will UI change be  visible to user? I mean, lets say there are two grids which user can export to pdf. Currently the user is viewing 1st grid. Now he presses export and i again give him the option of which grid they want to export, So if they select the 2nd grid, will the 2nd grid be visible on the UI?

Comment: How would I dynamically add the data to the html file from C# code. I have just created a simple wpf application with xaml and C# file. How would I use Html file in my aplication, load the data into it and then export it. Totally new in this, so again got back to square 1